# Knockout JS removes jQuery change event

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, jquery, knockoutjs

I don't know if it is specific to Magento 2 but an already set up HTML node with jQuery `change` event attached to it will lose its `change` event when run inside a knockout component with attached VM (view model).

**Situation in Magento:**

I moved the [product options wrapper](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml#L68) via a layout xml into a custom block

```xml
<referenceBlock name="product.info.form.options">
    // Custom block definition
    <move element="product.info.options.wrapper" destination="custom.block" />
</referenceBlock>
```

*That works without any issues!*

Now when wrapping around this moved block a knockout model with Magentos [custom "scope" binding](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html), all applied `onChange` events are getting removed - which means in this case the configurable option select boxes staying disabled.

The `change` events are getting applied [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js#L166)

```js
$(element).on('change', this, this._configure);
```

.. which also seems right for me on how to add an event.

So in my template file I do the following to wrap my knockout component (with attached VM) around this html snippet:

```html
<div class="tab-content" data-step="1" data-bind="scope:'times'">
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product_options_wrapper'); ?>
</div>
```

With `change` event on product wrapper dropdowns:

[image]

Withoout `change` event on dropdowns when nested inside Knockout component:

[image]

Anybody knows if this a thing between KnockoutJS and jQuery or if this has something to do with Magento?

*For reference on StackOverflow:*

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113064/jquery-change-event-removed-when-in-knockout-scope

Comment: i think is no a magento issue, but a ko and jquery conflict, try googling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the on change event is removed (conflict maybe?), but you can do something similar with Knockout itself:

```
<select data-bind="event:{ change: yourFunction}">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

#### Helpful links

This looks better practice to me rather than mixing KO and jQuery.

- There is a Fiddle with a none Magento example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LBz6d/).
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937131/knockoutjs-select-change-event-doesnt-fire-the-first-time) is also pretty helpful.
- [Select option binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html)
- [Options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)

Comment: The thing is, I want to use the configurable attribute filter options incl. the logic Magento already ships with. So the dependency between multiple options getting enabled/disabled - that is why I moved the complete wrapper and why I cannot apply my own event. Hope that was clear.. oO

Comment: If it has to be done with the default functionality then I have no idea sorry :(